# ToggleClass для селектов

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется данный код

```
$(function() {
    $("select.view").change(function(){
        var item = "." + $(this).val();
        $(item).removeClass("dnone");
    });
});
```

Как затуглить класс, к примеру выбрали option 1 сработала функция, выбрал option 2 функция обратно добавила класс dnone для элемента option 1?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYmJPJ

Comment: просто добавьте класс `option` для всех дивов, и добавляйте им всем `"dnone"` перед тем как его убрать у текущего

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $("select.view").change(function(){
        var item = "." + $(this).val();
      $(item).siblings("div").addClass('dnone')
        $(item).removeClass("dnone");
    });
});
```

Comment: Работает, но что вставить вместо div?

Comment: ибо div селект пропадает

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWegjE Ниче вроде не пропадает

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gaBGgX

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avRLWv Верстку то вы сменили , добавте условие типа `$(item).siblings("div[class^=option]").addClass('dnone')`

Answer (score 0):

Вобще то для таких дел оборачивают "склоняемые элементы."

А по-вашему:

```
$("div.dnone").addClass('toggled');
$("select.view").on('change', function(event){
    var tgt = "." + $(event.target).val();
    $('.toggled').addClass('dnone');
    $(tgt).removeClass('dnone'); 
});
```